# php variables in html form action

Tags: php, forms

I have the following action in my form:

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="print.php?naam=<?=$naam;?>&postcodehuisnummer=<?=$postcodehuisnummer?>&fietskeuze=<?=$src?>&fietstype=<?=$fietskeuze?>&framemaat=<?=$frame?>&opties=<?=$opties?>&optieid=<?=$optieid?>&huurdatum=<?=$today?>&einddatum=<?=$Einddatum?>&aantaldagen=<?=$dagenprijs?>">
```

On the `print.php` page I tried to read the variables with POST (and to test with GET too), but the variables are not being send.

With `print.php` on my screen I see the following line in the address URL bar:

```
http://localhost:8080/tablet1/print.php?naam=%3C?=$naam;?%3E&postcodehuisnummer=%3C?=$postcodehuisnummer;?%3E&fietskeuze=%3C?=$src;?%3E&fietstype=%3C?=$fietskeuze;?%3E&framemaat=%3C?=$frame;?%3E&opties=%3C?=$opties;?%3E&optieid=%3C?=$optieid;?%3E&huurdatum=%3C?=$today;?%3E&einddatum=%3C?=$Einddatum;?%3E&aantaldagen=%3C?=$dagenprijs;?%3E
```

It looks like it ignores the php tags/variables from the form? How do I change it to get the variables passed to `print.php`?

Comment: Did you try longer version of opening tag - "<?php" ? Support of short opening tag can be disabled...

Comment: Is the form actually being generated in a PHP page? Because that sounds a lot like you've just  PHP tags into an HTML file.

Comment: http://php.net/language.basic-syntax.phpmode <- yes, not only sometimes the PHP manual can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you see in the url bar, I would say that there are two possibilities:

1. Short tags is not enabled. Try replacing tags like `<?=` with `<?php echo`;
2. You have put php in an html page (no `.php` extension).

As you are adding variables to the url (`GET` method), you would need to access them through `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the fact that `<?` and `<?=` are called short open tags, and are not always enabled (see the [short_open_tag directive](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.short-open-tag)).

Comment: working now. It was indeed the short open tag which was disabled. i forgot to check it, after i upgraded the php version. thanks for the suggestion!